# Text Input in CanvasView Class

Tags: java, android, text, android-canvas, user-input

I searched many questions but did not find any suitable solution of my problem.In CanvasView class there is a 3D space where I  create and freely move complex 3D objects made of simple elements. Here I need a possibility of text input using for instance an EditText to input a name of created object before I save it or before I load the saved one. T tryied two ways - first is as follows:
Main Activity:

```
public class Activity_Moving extends Activity {

private CanvasView customCanvas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

    customCanvas = (CanvasView) findViewById(R.id.signature_canvas);

}
public void saveName(View v) {
    customCanvas.saveName();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.javacodegeeks.androidcanvasexample.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Input file name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

CanvasView class - here I put an EditText, which should enable to input the filename used while saving or loading the file:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {

private EditText edText;

public CanvasView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    context = c;

    //edText.findViewById(editText);// Here it causes error  !!!!!

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    edText = new EditText(context);
    edText.findViewById(editText);// Here it does not cause error.

    //This is where everything is drawn

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //Here I am performing object movements and saving or loading of files 
    by touching certain screen coordinates.
    if (x > 650)
        if ((y > 420)&&(y < 490)) {saveName();}//Tady by se měl vložit název 
    //souboru.
    }

    public void saveName () {
        objName = edText.getText().toString();//THIS CAUSES STOPPING OF THE APPLICATION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Toast.makeText(context,"The name is "+objName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Even if the compilation is done OK, EditText is visible and it is possible to write the name in it and all the things are working, when the saveName method is activatd the application stops saying: "Unfortunately, Moving_Element (it is the name of the app) has stoped." (Moving_Element is the name of the app.)

And then the second way, which is to create EditText programatically in the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method when the app is running like this:

```
LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(context);
lL.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
EditText editTextView = new EditText(context);
editTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
editTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
editTextView.setHint("AHOJ");
editTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);//This does not affect the position 
at all.
lL.addView(editTextView);
lL.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
lL.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2-50, canvas.getHeight()/2+50);
// placing the edit text at specific co-ordinates:
canvas.translate(0, 0);
lL.draw(canvas);
```

LinearLayout and EditText are created, (To see it I set the Layout's BackgroundColor to LTGRAY,  EditText's to DKGRAY and Font's to WHITE), the hint is written but EditText created in the top left corner cannot be moved to desired location and what is more important it is not possible to write into it.
Please, let me know any solution. I prefer the first way with EditTest in XML file. Thank You !

Comment: I think you should use a relative layout, that way you can place views relative to each other.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. It does the same errors.